# clicar em link e abrir conteudo em div como um _blank

Tags: javascript, css, json, div

Eu preciso criar em link e fazer com que o conteúdo do arquivo chamado seja exibido dentro de uma div de acordo com os $_GET[] informados.

Este comando eu já entendi como deve ser feito.

Entretanto, eu preciso que esta div seja aberta como se fosse um _blank.
ela não ficaria fixa em alguma parte da tela e também não ficaria preenchida com display: none e seria exibido habilitanda display ao clicar.

O conteúdo seria buscado no momento em que a DIV fosse aberta como acontece com as divs que são abertas no facebook.

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

```
function carregar(pagina){
    $("#conteudo").load(pagina);
}
```

- Arquivo 1
- Arquivo 2

```
<div id="conteudo"></div>
```

eu colei o código,mas ele não aparece aqui. não sei como fazer esta configuração.

Comment: Como acontece com as divs que são abertas no facebook.

Comment: coloque o que vc ja tem, parte do codigo

Comment: inserido o codigo

Comment: Pode usar modal do bootstrap.

Comment: Fala Leonardo. Eu vi sobre o bootstrap e realmente ele é uma excelente ferramenta. Resolve o problema de abrir modal. Mas reparei que quando é aberta ela já fico com o conteúdo preenchido e faz um efeito como display: none e block. Fazer desta forma é tranquilo. Mas preciso que ao ser aberta a div seja carregada buscando o  conteúdo naquele momento, como ocorre com as divs no facebook. De qualquer forma agradeço sua ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

você cria uma página para receber esses dados, envia o id pela url, ja que é um get, e nessa página você faz um select dos dados baseado nesse id, pelo que eu entendi é isso que vc quer `<a href="pagina_dados.php?&id=<?php echo $row['id'];> ">`